# Constraint subset higher-order constraint

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-constraints, existential-type, higher-rank-types

Using the `GHC.Exts.Constraint` kind, I have a generalized existentially quantified data structure like this:

```
data Some :: (* -> Constraint) -> * where
  Specimen :: c a => a -> Some c
```

(In reality, my type is more complex than this; this is just a reduced example)

Now, let's say that I have a function which, for example, requires the `Enum` constraint, that I want to act on `Some c`'s. What I need to do is to check whether the `Enum` constraint is implied by `c`:

```
succSome :: Enum ⊆ c => Some c -> Some c
succSome (Specimen a) = Specimen $ succ a
```

How would I implement the `⊆` operator in this case? Is it possible?

Comment: is [`:-`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/constraints/0.3.3/doc/html/Data-Constraint.html#g:3) what you are looking for?

Comment: is7s: How would I use that operator in this context? I thought it could only be used on the value-level...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that `Enum` and `c` are not constraints by themselves: They have kind `* -> Constraint`, not kind `Constraint`. So what you want to express with `Enum ⊆ c` is: `c a` implies `Enum a` for all `a`.

#### Step 1 (explicit witnesses)

With `:-` from `Data.Constraint`, we can encode a witness of the constraint `d ⊆ c` at the value level:

```
type Impl c d = forall a . c a :- d a
```

We would like to use `Impl` in the definition of `succSome` as follows:

```
succSome :: Impl c Enum -> Some c -> Some c
succSome impl (Specimen a) = (Specimen $ succ a) \\ impl
```

But this fails with a type error, saying that GHC cannot deduce `c a0` from `c a`. Looks like GHC chooses the very general type `impl :: forall a0 . c a0 :- d a0` and then fails to deduce `c a0`. We would prefer the simpler type `impl :: c a :- d a` for the type variable `a` that was extracted from the `Specimen`. Looks like we have to help type inference along a bit.

#### Step 2 (explicit type annotation)

In order to provide an explicit type annotation to `impl`, we have to introduce the `a` and `c` type variables (using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension).

```
succSome :: forall c . Impl c Enum -> Some c -> Some c
succSome impl (Specimen (a :: a)) = (Specimen $ succ a) \\ (impl :: c a :- Enum a)
```

This works, but it is not exactly what the questions asks for.

#### Step 3 (using a type class)

The questions asks for encoding the `d ⊆ c` constraint with a type class. We can achieve this by having a class with a single method:

```
class Impl c d where
  impl :: c a :- d a

succSome :: forall c . Impl c Enum => Some c -> Some c
succSome (Specimen (a :: a)) = (Specimen $ succ a) \\ (impl :: c a :- Enum a)
```

#### Step 4 (usage example)

To actually use this, we have to provide instances for `Impl`. For example:

```
instance Impl Integral Enum where
  impl = Sub Dict

value :: Integral a => a
value = 5

specimen :: Some Integral
specimen = Specimen value

test :: Some Integral
test = succSome specimen
```

Comment: Regarding your first point: Yes, I understand that `Enum` and `c` are “kind functions;” however in my post I chose to treat them as classes/sets of types (which they are: type classes) which made the `⊆` appropriate I think.

Also, in my use-case I cannot provide a witness for every combination of `d` and `c` (Especially since either might be a N-ary tuple of classes), but since I don't think it's possible to ask GHC to perform this kind of proof-checking for me I'll accept this answer until someone maybe proves me wrong.

Comment: @dflemstr: What do you mean by "N-ary tuple of classes"? I think you cannot have something like `(Eq, Num)` but only something like `(Eq a, Num a)`. So how do you instantiate the `Some c` for more than one class?

Comment: By using e.g. `type Bla a = (Eq a, Show a)` which does, in a way, eta-reduce to a “N-ary tuple of classes.” *EDIT:* and I would then be using a `Some Bla` if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work, because in `Some Bla`, the type synonym `Bla` is not fully applied. Am I missing something?

Comment: Right... I was travelling and couldn't test my example... Still, if I have to use the trick `class (Eq a, Show a) => Bla a where` trick I still get a ton of witnesses to make.